# Sprinting in Watch_Dogs

Tags: watch-dogs

Is there a way to sprint in *Watch_Dogs*?

It seems that different NPC's run with different speed and some of them are just way faster than other ones. I noticed it after knocking out a few criminals(side missions?). The first few were really easy to chase and knock out, however after some time, these criminals start running faster and faster(or is it my tired brain that thinks that they run faster because I act slower?) and sometimes it takes a few minutes of non-stop running to get them.

So, is there a sprinting option in *Watch underscore Dogs*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chase missions are often scripted so you get to chase the npc's for a certain time before you are *allowed* to catch them.
Right trigger on gamepads and shift on keyboard lets you sprint and holding spacebar or A/X on gamepad helps you get over obstacles faster. It's the only way to "sprint".

Answer (score 0):

On the WiiU version, you can sprint by holding ZR button.